# "no escaping his influence" or "no escaping of his influence"

Tags: difference, gerunds

> There will be no escaping his influence on the English language.

I think since escaping is functioning as noun, it would be better to use "of" between "escaping" and " his influence" to add details to the gerund as opposed to linking them together. Please clarify me doubts.

Comment: With "of", the sentence would be more likely understood as "his influence's escaping", as opposed to "someone escaping his influence".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When “to escape” is transitive, the object is the thing you are getting away from. This is still true when it’s a gerund.

Or, put another way, “escaping X” is equivalent to “escape from X” rather than to “escape of X”.